# How can I show some data as a Table in R?

Tags: r

I am using the aggregate function to show the mean of log(wage) by gender and race.

```
aggregate.data.frame(log_wage, list(race=race,gender=gender),  FUN = mean)
```

This is the output:

```
  race gender        x
1 black female 2.726742
2 other female 2.858445
3 white female 2.819883
4 black   male 2.864154
5 other   male 3.027230
6 white   male 3.065787
```

How can I show the values as table like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jprxh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to answer your question:

**DATA**:

```
df <- data.frame(
  race = sample(c("black", "other", "white"), 100, replace = T),
  gender = sample(c("f", "m"), 100, replace = T),
  x = rnorm(100))
```

## EDIT:

The most elegant and quickest way to achieve your goal is to compute the means not via `aggregate` but via `tapply`, thus:

```
tapply(df$x, list(df$race, df$gender), mean)
```

The output is pretty much what you want:

```
                f          m
black  0.13584749  0.1928834
other -0.37386003  0.2078025
white -0.09913409 -0.1672589
```

**Other solution**:

This computes the means by `gender` and `race` using `aggregate`:

```
df1 <- aggregate(
  df$x,
  list(df$race, df$gender),
  FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE
)
df1
  Group.1 Group.2           x
1   black       f  0.13584749
2   other       f -0.37386003
3   white       f -0.09913409
4   black       m  0.19288337
5   other       m  0.20780250
6   white       m -0.16725892
```

To get more meaningful column names rename the columns:

```
colnames(df1) <- c("race", "gender", "x")
```

Change `df1`to wide format using `reshape`:

```
reshape(df1, idvar = "race", timevar = "gender", direction = "wide")
   race         x.f        x.m
1 black  0.13584749  0.1928834
2 other -0.37386003  0.2078025
3 white -0.09913409 -0.1672589
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used the "tapply" function